# Simple task library question

Tags: c#, unit-testing, concurrency

I'm new to task library. I want to run some of my unit tests in parallel and test the concurrency issues using task library in .NET 4.0.

As you know `TestMethod`s are parameter-less and return nothing (`void`) so I need just run one of my tests by `N` threads concurrently.

```
[TestMethod()]
void MyTest()
{
    // Do Something
}
```

It can be done by traditional threads, but wanna use a more robust and managed technique, so:

How to run `N` number of `MyTest()` simultaneously using `TaskLibrary`?

*I'm wondering why there's not a built-in attribute for concurrent unit-testing.*

Comment: There is usually more to concurrent testing than just running a big bunch. You want to test explicit timing scenarios, etc. A simple attribute wouldn't create a concurrent testing framework.

Comment: @Albin: Still it makes sense to me to have such attribute. Many times I saw people using loops for just running a test more than one time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[TestMethod()]
void MyTest()
{
    // Do Something
}

[TestMethod()]
void MyTest_4_Times()
{
    Parallel.Invoke(MyTest, MyTest, MyTest, MyTest);
}
```

or if you want to change the number of concurrent tests by a parameter.

```
[TestMethod()]
void MyTest_4_Times()
{
    var n = 4;
    Task.WaitAll(Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select(_ => Task.Factory.StartNew(MyTest)).ToArray());
}
```